# Не срабатывает поиск по базе

Tags: mysql, python, django

viewes.py

```
from Mysitez.models import AutoParsingMan
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
def search(request):
if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    list = AutoParsingMan.objects.filter(marka__icontains=q)
    return render_to_response('Mysitez/seach.html',
        {'list': list, 'querty': q})
else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

seach.html

```
{% extends 'Mysitez/base.html' %}

<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if list %}
    <ul>
    {% for AutoParsingMan in list %}
    <li>{{ AutoParsingMan.marka }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No marks matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
 from django.db import models as m
 class AutoParsingMan(m.Model):
date_ins = m.DateTimeField()
date_change = m.DateTimeField()
change = m.CharField(max_length=15)
date = m.DateTimeField()
date_task = m.DateField()
marka = m.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'auto_parsing_man'
```

база и колонки доступны по incpectdb

ок - убрал расширение базового шаблона

начало выводить лист точек, те фильтр работает и чтото выводится

изменю вопрос - как сделать чтоб выдавались нормальные данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в модель

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.marka
```